# XMonad focus hook

Tags: haskell, x11, xmonad

I would like to configure XMonad so that a certain `IO ()` function is evaluated whenever a window is focused, so that I can change some aspects of the environment depending on which window this was. I can't seem to find anything about this in the docs, but I'm sure it exists so presumably I'm looking for the wrong keyword.

Comment: Are you trying to perform an action when a specific window is focused, or when any window is focused? The latter is much harder than the former (I'm not familiar with any modules that give a so-called focus hook).

Comment: When a specific window is focused would be fine, if I can also have something happen when it's unfocused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing is probably `logHook :: !(X ())` in the [`XConfig`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t%3aXConfig). You can get the focused window and run your `IO` action to update the environment, but this hook is described as "The action to perform when the window set is changed", so your `updateEnv` could be called multiple times in a row with the same window ID (when you swap windows without changing focus, for example).

```
myLogHook = gets (peek . windowset) >>= liftIO . updateEnv
  where
    updateEnv :: Maybe Window -> IO ()
    updateEnv = undefined
```

Comment: I think this is what I want; I'll upvote and accept it once I've had time to verify that it works.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to customize [`handleEventHook`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#v%3ahandleEventHook).

Something like this :

```
myEventHook e@(CrossingEvent {ev_event_type=t, ev_window=win}) 
        | t == enterNotify = do 
                   something with win
                   return $ All True
        | t == leaveNotify = do 
                   something else
                   return $ All True
        | otherwise = return $ All True
```

Comment: Because `CrossingEvent`s are tied to the mouse pointer, that doesn't do anything when you use the keyboard to change focus, unless you use something like `XMonad.Actions.UpdatePointer` to make the pointer follow.

Comment: @raymonad focusIn/focusOut would be the correct events, but it doesn't seem possible to get them (I tried with AnyEvent). I don't know why.

Comment: @Leiaz I think you need to change the clientMask that XMonad is using. ([xmonad.org/docu](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Operations.html#clientMask)). Surely there's a way to add the `focusChangeMask` to it, but I can't figure how.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous options, I built my own. @Leiza, I found how to use `clientMask`:

```hs
import XMonad
-- import Data.Monoid (All(..))
import Control.Monad (when)
...
hook :: Event -> X All
hook (AnyEvent {ev_event_type = et}) = do
  when (et == focusOut) $
    <action>
  return (All True)
hook _ = return (All True)
...
main = do
...
  clientMask = focusChangeMask .|. clientMask def
...
```

@Leiza was right, for me *CrossingEvents* not works properly.